# Optimizing seemingly a simple exponential function

Tags: optimization, exponential-function, convex-optimization

I want to find the optimal solution to the following seemingly simple function:

$$\max_{x \in [0, 1]}~f(x) = x\mathrm{e}^{-a\left(bx^t+1\right)^\frac{1}{1-t}},$$
where $a, b > 0$ and $t \in (0, 1)$.

**My attempt**: I tried obtaining the optimal solution $x^*$ by exploring its properties. For example, I took the first derivative of $f(x)$ with respect to $x$, which is
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} f(x)}{\mathrm{d} x} = \dfrac{\left(\left(t-1\right)\left(bx^t+1\right)^\frac{t}{t-1}+abtx^t\right)\exp\left({-\frac{a}{\left(bx^t+1\right)^{1/(t-1)}}}\right)}{\left(t-1\right)\left(bx^t+1\right)^\frac{t}{t-1}}.$$
The above derivative seems to not yield $x^*$ when the derivative is equated to $0$. How can one get the optimal solution or at least some properties regarding the optimal solution such as uniqueness and reasonable bounds on the optimal solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that it is true that:

$$
x^* = \text{argmax}_{x\in[0,1]} f(x) = \text{argmax}_{x\in[0,1]} \log(f(x))
$$
since $\log(\bullet)$ is an increasing function. Note that:
$$
\log(f(x)) = \log(x) - a(bx^t+1)^{\frac{1}{1-t}}
$$
Hence,
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\log(f(x)) = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{abt}{1-t} (bx^t+1)^{\frac{1}{1-t} - 1}\frac{x^{t}}{x} 
$$
if we set $\frac{d}{dx}\log(f(x))=0$ we obtain:
$$
\frac{abt}{1-t} (bx^t+1)^{\frac{1}{1-t} - 1}\frac{x^t}{x}  = \frac{1}{x}
$$
Assume, $x\neq 0$. Then,$\frac{abt}{1-t} (bx^t+1)^{\frac{1}{1-t} - 1}x^{t} = 1$.

Now, note that $b(\bullet)^t+1$ is an increasing and positive function, and the same for $(\bullet)^{\frac{1}{1-t}-1}$ and $(\bullet)^t$ since $\frac{1}{1-t}-1>0$. Hence, $g(x;a,b,t) = \frac{abt}{1-t} (bx^t+1)^{\frac{1}{1-t} - 1}x^t $ is an increasing function.

Now, to see if there is a solution to $g(x^*;a,b,t)=1$ in $(0,1)$ we use the fact that $g(0;a,b,t)=0$ and $g(1;a,b,t) = \frac{abt}{1-t} (b+1)^{\frac{1}{1-t} - 1}$. Since, $g(x;a,b,t)$ is continuous and increasing, there exists a solution of $g(x^*;a,b,t)=1$ with $0< x^*< 1$ only if $g(1;a,b,t) = \frac{abt}{1-t} (b+1)^{\frac{1}{1-t} - 1}> 1$.

Once you find this unique $x^*$, the only thing left is to compare the cost function $f(x^*)$ with the value at the boundaries of the interval, this is with $f(0)$ and $f(1)$. Note that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1) = \exp(-a(b+1)^\frac{1}{1-t})\geq f(0)=0$. If $x^*$ inside $(0,1)$ doesn't exists (if $\frac{abt}{1-t} (b+1)^{\frac{1}{1-t} - 1}<1$) or $f(x^*)\leq f(1)$ for such $x^*\in(0,1)$, then the optimal is certainly $x=1$.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there a way to find the conditions on the existence of the unique solution in terms of $a$, $b$, and $t$?

Comment: I'm working on it, but I believe the answer is yes...

Comment: @Oscar check out my new version of the answer

Comment: Thanks. I did not get the last line "If $x^∗$ does not exist,..." Is the line not contradictory since $x^∗=1$? Overall, from your answer, it seems that the optimal x always exists, right?

Comment: Oh sure, I meant that if "$x^*$ does not exist in the interior of $(0,1)$, then the optimal must be $x^*=1$", my bad. I corrected the answer. And yes, if $f(x)$ is continuous and bounded, and the interval for $x$ is closed, then, there will always be an optimal $x^*$. However, it might be in the boundaries of the domain of $f$ and not a point with $\frac{df}{dx}=0$.

Comment: Thanks! The answer was insightful. Now, I have a bigger problem to solve, which is an extension of this optimization problem. I tried the new problem the way you approached this problem, but I could not proceed after few steps. If you are interested, please have a look at the new problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3838394/optimizing-sum-of-two-exponential-functions. As you will see, it is of the similar type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just did some plotting. For some values of $a$ and $b$ there is a max around $t=0.5$ and $x=0.1$ and for other values there is a max at the boundary at $t=0$ and $x=1$.

For finding the max over $x$ and $t$, you can also set $df/dt=0$ to get another equation. But I'm not sure if that helps.

Good luck :)