# Optimizing sum of two exponential functions

Tags: optimization, exponential-function, convex-optimization, exponential-sum

I want to find the optimal solution to the following seemingly sum of two exponential functions:

$$\max_{x \in [0, 1]}~f(x) = \underbrace{x\exp\left(-a\left(bx^t+1\right)^\frac{1}{1-t}\right)}_{f_{1}(x)} + \underbrace{(1-x)\exp\left(-c(1-x)^{\frac{t}{1-t}}\right)}_{f_2(x)},$$
where $a, b, c > 0$ and $t \in (0, 1)$.

**My attempt**: I tried obtaining the optimal solution $x^*$ by exploring its properties. For example, I did the following:
\begin{align}&\frac{\mathrm{d} f(x)}{\mathrm{d} x} = 0
\end{align}
which results in
$$\frac{\mathrm{d} f_1(x)}{\mathrm{d} x} = -\frac{\mathrm{d} f_2(x)}{\mathrm{d} x}.$$
Thus, taking the first derivatives of $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ with respect to $x$ yields
$$
\dfrac{\left(\left(t-1\right)\left(bx^t+1\right)^\frac{t}{t-1}+abtx^t\right)\mathrm{e}^{-\frac{a}{\left(bx^t+1\right)^{1/(t-1)}}}}{\left(bx^t+1\right)^\frac{t}{t-1}} = \left(ct\left(1-x\right)^\frac{t}{1-t}+t-1\right)\mathrm{e}^{-c\left(1-x\right)^\frac{t}{1-t}}.
$$
Now, the right hand side is positive and increasing only if $ct\left(1-x\right)^\frac{t}{1-t}+t-1 > 0$. But I cannot find a trend in the left hand side to say something about the uniqueness of the optimal solution $x^*$ and the conditions on the existence of $x^*$. How can one get the optimal solution or at least some properties regarding the optimal solution such as uniqueness and reasonable bounds on the optimal solution?

Comment: *two simple exponential functions ?*

Comment: It might not be possible to solve the problem explicitly. Rather, you will need to use an iterative scheme to get an optimal solution. Since you have a compact domain ($x\in [0,1]) then we know a solution exists. If the function in hand is concave (this needs to be checked) then the problem can be solved relatively easy. Even if not, it should still be possible since it is a 1-D problem, therefore mapping all stationary points can be reasonable time

Comment: I agree. The optimal solution can be obtained numerically with ease. However, if possible, I am interested in the structural properties of the optimal solution to gain more insight into the problem, especially uniqueness, its existence, and how the optimal solution depends on other parameters such as $a, b, c$ and $t$.

Comment: @Oscar A minimizer exists since you have a compact domain. If you can show that the function is strictly concave then it is also unique. Otherwise, I admit that the rather complex structure of exponents and powers, couple with 4 parameters makes it challenging to analyze the function (not to say it's impossible).